# ListBox to be filled based on the selection in the previous List Box (Module-pool)

Tags: abap

I have a DYNPRO 010 which has 2 listbox (dropdownlist), and I want to fill the second one `PEP` after selected the first one `PROJ` automatically, with no enter key pressed.

It works when I choose a value in listbox1 and I press the enter.

Screen 010:

```
PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
  Chain.
    field: 
       wa_screen_010-proj MODULE iniciativa ON REQUEST,
       wa_screen_010-pep  MODULE field_validation.
  Endchain.
```

ABAP code for module `iniciativa`:

```
MODULE iniciativa INPUT.

  DATA: ld_field     TYPE VRM_ID ,
        it_listbox   TYPE VRM_VALUES,
        wa_listbox   LIKE LINE OF it_listbox,
        it_prps      TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF prps,
        wa_prps LIKE LINE OF it_prps.

  SELECT  peps~pspnr peps~posid peps~post1 peps~stufe
         INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_prps
         FROM proj AS proyecto
         LEFT JOIN prps AS peps
         ON proyecto~pspnr = peps~psphi
         WHERE proyecto~pspid  = WA_SCREEN_010-PROJ .

  DELETE it_prps where stufe ne 2.

   loop at it_prps into wa_prps.
    wa_listbox-key = wa_prps-posid .
    wa_listbox-text = wa_prps-posid.
    append wa_listbox to it_listbox.
  endloop.

   ld_field = 'WA_SCREEN_010-INICIATIVA'.
  CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
    EXPORTING
      id     = ld_field
      values = it_listbox.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the first list box active by assigning a function code to it. This triggers a PAI-PBO-cycle. Make sure that the function code does not trigger any unwanted function.

Comment: works nice..
Do you know how to fill the listbox when i put a choose a value from an input text. ?